# Angular kendo grid [Navigable]

Tags: angular

Hello  We have a licenced paid kendo angular grid  1.7.1  in my work.   I am trying to implement the [navigable] directive in get keyboard grid navigation.   But this directive is unknown.  What do I have to do or install?   Thanks

Comment: is it support from kendo team?

Comment: I guess by thier documentation it is supposed to be supported